# I need help to store my image in internal directory and its path is insert in SQLite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to store large BLOBS or similar data in the SQLite database because rightnow I can't upload image with size more than 2mb

the solution for this problem's store my image in internal directory and its path is insert in SQLite DB

I've been trying to fix this past 3 days because im new in Java and i dont know how to store it

I will really appreciate if you can help me solve this

Here's my code :

CrudActivity

```
    EditText mEdtName, mEdtStok, mEdtJual;
    Button mBtnAdd, mBtnList;
    ImageView mImageView;

    final int REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY = 999;

    public static SQLiteHelper mSQLiteHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crud);

        mEdtName = findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        mEdtStok = findViewById(R.id.edtStok);
        mEdtJual = findViewById(R.id.edtJual);
        mBtnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        mBtnList = findViewById(R.id.btnList);
        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        //creating database
        mSQLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this, "RECORDDB.sqlite", null, 1);

        //creating table in database
        mSQLiteHelper.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RECORD(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR, stok VARCHAR, jual VARCHAR, image BLOB)");


        //select image by on imageview click
        mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //read external storage permission to select image from gallery
                //runtime permission for devices android 6.0 and above
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        CrudActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY
                );
            }
        });

        //add record to sqlite
        mBtnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    mSQLiteHelper.insertData(
                            mEdtName.getText().toString().trim(),
                            mEdtStok.getText().toString().trim(),
                            mEdtJual.getText().toString().trim(),
                            imageViewToByte(mImageView)
                    );
                    Toast.makeText(CrudActivity.this, "Added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //reset views
                    mEdtName.setText("");
                    mEdtStok.setText("");
                    mEdtJual.setText("");
                    mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.addphoto);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        //show record list
        mBtnList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //start recordlist activity
                startActivity(new Intent(CrudActivity.this, RecordListActivity.class));
            }
        });


    }

    public static byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView image) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        return byteArray;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY){
            if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                //gallery intent
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Don't have permission to access file location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            final int takeFlags = intent.getFlags()
                    & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
// Check for the freshest data.
            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(imageUri, takeFlags);
            CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON) //enable image guidlines
                    .setAspectRatio(1,1)// image will be square
                    .start(this);

        }
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
            CropImage.ActivityResult result =CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                //set image choosed from gallery to image view
                mImageView.setImageURI(resultUri);
            }
            else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE){
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }

        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

SQLiteHelper

```
  public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //constructor
    SQLiteHelper(Context context,
                 String name,
                 SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
                 int version){
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    public void queryData(String sql){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        database.execSQL(sql);
    }

    //insertData
    public void insertData(String name, String stok, String jual, byte[] image){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        //query to insert record in database table
        String sql = "INSERT INTO RECORD VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; //where "RECORD" is table name in database we will create in mainActivity

        SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
        statement.clearBindings();

        statement.bindString(1, name);
        statement.bindString(2, stok);
        statement.bindString(3, jual);
        statement.bindBlob(4, image);

        statement.executeInsert();
    }

    //updateData
    public void updateData(String name, String stok, String jual, byte[] image, int id){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        //query to update record
        String sql = "UPDATE RECORD SET name=?, stok=?, jual=?, image=? WHERE id=?";

        SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);

        statement.bindString(1, name);
        statement.bindString(2, stok);
        statement.bindString(3, jual);
        statement.bindBlob(4, image);
        statement.bindDouble(5, (double)id);

        statement.execute();
        database.close();
    }

    //deleteData
    public void deleteData(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        //query to delete record using id
        String sql = "DELETE FROM RECORD WHERE id=?";

        SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
        statement.clearBindings();
        statement.bindDouble(1, (double)id);

        statement.execute();
        database.close();
    }

    public Cursor getData(String sql){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
        return database.rawQuery(sql, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

RecordListActivity

```
public class RecordListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView mListView;
    ArrayList<Model> mList;
    RecordListAdapter mAdapter = null;

    ImageView imageViewIcon;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_record_list);

        mListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mList = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new RecordListAdapter(this, R.layout.row, mList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        //get all data from sqlite
        SQLiteHelper mSQLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this, "RECORDDB.sqlite", null, 1);
        Cursor cursor = mSQLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM RECORD");
        mList.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            String stok = cursor.getString(2);
            String jual = cursor.getString(3);
            byte[] image  = cursor.getBlob(4);
            //add to list
            mList.add(new Model(id, name, stok, jual, image));
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (mList.size()==0){
            //if there is no record in table of database which means listview is empty
            Toast.makeText(this, "No record found...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long l) {
                //alert dialog to display options of update and delete
                final CharSequence[] items = {"Update", "Delete"};

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecordListActivity.this);

                dialog.setTitle("Choose an action");
                dialog.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        if (i == 0){
                            //update
                            Cursor c = CrudActivity.mSQLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id FROM RECORD");
                            ArrayList<Integer> arrID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                            while (c.moveToNext()){
                                arrID.add(c.getInt(0));
                            }
                            //show update dialog
                            showDialogUpdate(RecordListActivity.this, arrID.get(position));
                        }
                        if (i==1){
                            //delete
                            Cursor c = CrudActivity.mSQLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id FROM RECORD");
                            ArrayList<Integer> arrID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                            while (c.moveToNext()){
                                arrID.add(c.getInt(0));
                            }
                            showDialogDelete(arrID.get(position));
                        }
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        });


    }

    private void showDialogDelete(final int idRecord) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogDelete = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecordListActivity.this);
        dialogDelete.setTitle("Warning!!");
        dialogDelete.setMessage("Are you sure to delete?");
        dialogDelete.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                try {
                    CrudActivity.mSQLiteHelper.deleteData(idRecord);
                    Toast.makeText(RecordListActivity.this, "Delete successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
                }
                updateRecordList();
            }
        });
        dialogDelete.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialogDelete.show();
    }

    private void showDialogUpdate(Activity activity, final int position){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.update_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Update");

        imageViewIcon = dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageViewRecord);
        final EditText edtName = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        final EditText edtStok = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtStok);
        final EditText edtJual = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtJual);
        Button btnUpdate = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

        //set width of dialog
        int width = (int)(activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels*0.95);
        //set hieght of dialog
        int height = (int)(activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels*0.7);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width,height);
        dialog.show();

        //in update dialog click image view to update image
        imageViewIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //check external storage permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        RecordListActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        888
                );
            }
        });
        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    CrudActivity.mSQLiteHelper.updateData(
                            edtName.getText().toString().trim(),
                            edtStok.getText().toString().trim(),
                            edtJual.getText().toString().trim(),
                            CrudActivity.imageViewToByte(imageViewIcon),
                            position
                    );
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (Exception error){
                    Log.e("Update error", error.getMessage());
                }
                updateRecordList();
            }
        });

    }

    private void updateRecordList() {
        //get all data from sqlite
        Cursor cursor = CrudActivity.mSQLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM RECORD");
        mList.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            String stok = cursor.getString(2);
            String jual = cursor.getString(3);
            byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(4);

            mList.add(new Model(id,name,stok,jual,image));
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public static byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView image) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        return byteArray;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 888){
            if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                //gallery intent
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 888);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Don't have permission to access file location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        if (requestCode == 888 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            final int takeFlags = intent.getFlags()
                    & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
// Check for the freshest data.
            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(imageUri, takeFlags);
            CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON) //enable image guidlines
                    .setAspectRatio(1,1)// image will be square
                    .start(this);
        }
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
            CropImage.ActivityResult result =CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                //set image choosed from gallery to image view
                imageViewIcon.setImageURI(resultUri);
            }
            else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE){
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you edit your question with the error?

Comment: Please try to reduce your sample code to the minimum needed to show your problem. This is just too much to take in.

Comment: There's no error to the code that i post here @juanjo, its just give me no data  because i store large image using blob.

Comment: already done it @mumpitz

Answer (score 2):

The following demonstration will store an image either in the database or to internal storage within the app.

If the image size is < 256k (as per `public static final int MAX_IMAGESIZETOSTORE = 1024 * 256;`) then it will be stored in the db and be retrievable from the database.

If the image is 256k or more (with a limit of 16MB imposed for the demo as per `public static final int MAXIMAGEBUFFER = 1024 * 1024 * 16;`) then it will be stored in the App's Files/myimagestores directory (myimagestores directory being created by the demo) and the path to the image is stored in the database.

The demo rather than getting images from a camera, gets the images from the assets folder (5 were used for the demo).

**The code will not work properly if the images are not in the assets folder and if they are not defined with matching names as per** :-

```
String[] imagesToGet = new String[]{"sample001.jpg","sample002.jpg","sample003.jpg","sample004.jpg","sample005.jpg"};
```

## The code

### SQLiteHelper.java

- this is basically your helper with a modified **insertData** method that being

:-

```
public long insertData(String name, String stok, String jual, byte[] image) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(RECORD_COL_NAME,name);
    cv.put(RECORD_COL_STOK,stok);
    cv.put(RECORD_COL_JUAL,jual);
    if (image.length > 0 && image.length < MAX_IMAGESIZETOSTORE) {
        cv.put(RECORD_COL_IMAGE,image);
    } else {
            cv.put(RECORD_COL_IMAGEPATH,StoreImage.storeImage(mContext,image,name));
    }
    return db.insert(TBLNAME_RECORD,null,cv);
}
```

The following constants are declared at the class level :-

```
public static final int MAX_IMAGESIZETOSTORE = 1024 * 256;

public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

public static final String TBLNAME_RECORD = "record";
public static final String RECORD_COl_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
public static final String RECORD_COL_NAME = "name";
public static final String RECORD_COL_STOK = "stok";
public static final String RECORD_COL_JUAL = "jual";
public static final String RECORD_COL_IMAGE = "image";
public static final String RECORD_COL_IMAGEPATH = "imagepath";
```

- as can be seen an additional column, **imagepath** has been added to store the path to image (null if the image is store in the db and vice-versa that is if the image is not stored in the db but as a file then the **image** column will be null).

## StoreImage.java is

:-

```
public class StoreImage {

    public static final String IMAGESTOREDIRECTORY = "myimagestore";

    public static String storeImage(Context context, byte[] image, String imagename) {

        File mFilesDirectory = context.getFilesDir();
        File mImageStoreDirectory = new File(mFilesDirectory.getPath() + File.separator + IMAGESTOREDIRECTORY);
        if (!mImageStoreDirectory.exists()) {
            mImageStoreDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
        File mImageStore = new File(mImageStoreDirectory.getPath() + File.separator + imagename);
        OutputStream os;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(mImageStore);
            os.write(image);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mImageStore.getPath();
    }
}
```

As can be seen from the above the **storeImage** method of the **StoreImage** class stores the image, (the byte[] passed to the **insertData** method of the **SQliteHelper** class.

As can also be seen the above will create the **myimagestore** directory if need be.

## MainActivity.java is

:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int MAXIMAGEBUFFER = 1024 * 1024 * 16;
    SQLiteHelper mDBHlpr;

    // The demo images copied into the assets folder
    String[] imagesToGet = new String[]{"sample001.jpg","sample002.jpg","sample003.jpg","sample004.jpg","sample005.jpg"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHlpr = new SQLiteHelper(this);

        for (String s: imagesToGet) {
            mDBHlpr.insertData(s,"stock for " + s,"jual for " + s,getImage(s));
        }

        Cursor csr = mDBHlpr.getData("SELECT * FROM RECORD;");
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr.close();
    }


    //Get a demo image from the assets folder
    private byte[] getImage(String name) {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getAssets().openFd(name);
            long fsz = afd.getLength();
            if (fsz < MAXIMAGEBUFFER) {
                InputStream is = this.getAssets().open(name);
                buffer = new byte[(int) fsz];
                is.read(buffer, 0, (int) fsz);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

The **getImage** method, the bulk of the activity, retrieves an image from the assets folder (the demo images).

The 5 demo images are processed in a loop and added to the database via the **insertData** method.

After the inserts the all data is extracted into a Cursor and the Cursor is dumped (written to the log).

## Example Run :-

With the images copied into the assets folder as per :-

[image]

And the App run then the log contains :-

```
06-01 08:59:14.828 7728-7728/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@cd7f7ce
06-01 08:59:14.828 7728-7728/? I/System.out: 0 {
06-01 08:59:14.828 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    _id=1
06-01 08:59:14.828 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    name=sample001.jpg
06-01 08:59:14.828 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    stok=stock for sample001.jpg
06-01 08:59:14.828 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    jual=jual for sample001.jpg
06-01 08:59:14.828 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    image=null
06-01 08:59:14.828 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    imagepath=/data/user/0/s.e.so56392635storeimage/files/myimagestore/sample001.jpg
06-01 08:59:14.828 7728-7728/? I/System.out: }
06-01 08:59:14.828 7728-7728/? I/System.out: 1 {
06-01 08:59:14.828 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    _id=2
06-01 08:59:14.828 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    name=sample002.jpg
06-01 08:59:14.828 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    stok=stock for sample002.jpg
06-01 08:59:14.828 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    jual=jual for sample002.jpg
06-01 08:59:14.828 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    image=null
06-01 08:59:14.828 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    imagepath=/data/user/0/s.e.so56392635storeimage/files/myimagestore/sample002.jpg
06-01 08:59:14.828 7728-7728/? I/System.out: }
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out: 2 {
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    _id=3
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    name=sample003.jpg
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    stok=stock for sample003.jpg
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    jual=jual for sample003.jpg
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    image=null
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    imagepath=/data/user/0/s.e.so56392635storeimage/files/myimagestore/sample003.jpg
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out: }
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out: 3 {
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    _id=4
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    name=sample004.jpg
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    stok=stock for sample004.jpg
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    jual=jual for sample004.jpg
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    image=<unprintable>
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    imagepath=null
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out: }
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out: 4 {
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    _id=5
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    name=sample005.jpg
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    stok=stock for sample005.jpg
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    jual=jual for sample005.jpg
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    image=<unprintable>
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out:    imagepath=null
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out: }
06-01 08:59:14.829 7728-7728/? I/System.out: <<<<<
```

This indicates that sample001.jpg -  sample003.jpg were stored as files e.g. sample001.jpg was stored (s far as the db is concerned) at **/data/user/0/s.e.so56392635storeimage/files/myimagestore/sample001.jpg**

- obviously the package name will be as per the package used, sometimes you may see **/data/data/the_package_name/files/myimagestore/sample001.jpg**

And also for those 3 images the **image** column is **null**.

For the other two (smaller) images, the **image** column is **unprintable** (i.e. a BLOB) and the **imagepath** column is **null**.

In addition to the above test/check the following two screen shots, verify that the larger photos have been stored.

First the assets folder showing file sizes as per the assets folder :-

[image]

Second the App's internal storage (data/data/) :-

[image]

***sample004.jpg*** and **sample005.jpg** don't appear as they have been stored in the DB.

Finally as proof that smaller images have been stored then a simple modification to the query that extracts the cursor as per :-

```
Cursor csr = mDBHlpr.getData("SELECT *, length(" + SQLiteHelper.RECORD_COL_IMAGE + ") FROM RECORD;");
```

results in :-

```
06-01 09:16:36.282 I/System.out:    _id=4
06-01 09:16:36.282 I/System.out:    name=sample004.jpg
06-01 09:16:36.282 I/System.out:    stok=stock for sample004.jpg
06-01 09:16:36.282 I/System.out:    jual=jual for sample004.jpg
06-01 09:16:36.282 I/System.out:    image=<unprintable>
06-01 09:16:36.282 I/System.out:    imagepath=null
06-01 09:16:36.282 I/System.out:    length(image)=9000 <<<<<<<<<<<<
06-01 09:16:36.283 I/System.out: }
06-01 09:16:36.283 I/System.out: 4 {
06-01 09:16:36.283 I/System.out:    _id=5
06-01 09:16:36.283 I/System.out:    name=sample005.jpg
06-01 09:16:36.283 I/System.out:    stok=stock for sample005.jpg
06-01 09:16:36.283 I/System.out:    jual=jual for sample005.jpg
06-01 09:16:36.283 I/System.out:    image=<unprintable>
06-01 09:16:36.283 I/System.out:    imagepath=null
06-01 09:16:36.283 I/System.out:    length(image)=28239 <<<<<<<<<<<<
```

## Additional SQliteHelper.java

Here's complete SQLiteHelper.java :-

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int MAX_IMAGESIZETOSTORE = 1024 * 256;

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TBLNAME_RECORD = "record";
    public static final String RECORD_COl_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String RECORD_COL_NAME = "name";
    public static final String RECORD_COL_STOK = "stok";
    public static final String RECORD_COL_JUAL = "jual";
    public static final String RECORD_COL_IMAGE = "image";
    public static final String RECORD_COL_IMAGEPATH = "imagepath";

    Context mContext;

    //constructor <<<<<<<<<< MODIFIED so just requires Context 
    //!!!!!!!!!!NOTE!!!!!!!!!! uses database/tables as defined in this class
    public SQLiteHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void queryData(String sql){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        database.execSQL(sql);
    }

    public long insertData(String name, String stok, String jual, byte[] image) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(RECORD_COL_NAME,name);
        cv.put(RECORD_COL_STOK,stok);
        cv.put(RECORD_COL_JUAL,jual);
        if (image.length > 0 && image.length < MAX_IMAGESIZETOSTORE) {
            cv.put(RECORD_COL_IMAGE,image);
        } else {
                cv.put(RECORD_COL_IMAGEPATH,StoreImage.storeImage(mContext,image,name));
        }
        return db.insert(TBLNAME_RECORD,null,cv);
    }

    //insertData
    /**
    public void insertData(String name, String stok, String jual, byte[] image){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        //query to insert record in database table
        String sql = "INSERT INTO RECORD VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; //where "RECORD" is table name in database we will create in mainActivity

        SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
        statement.clearBindings();
        statement.bindString(1, name);
        statement.bindString(2, stok);
        statement.bindString(3, jual);
        statement.bindBlob(4, image);
        statement.executeInsert();
    }
     **/

    //updateData
    public void updateData(String name, String stok, String jual, byte[] image, int id){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        //query to update record
        String sql = "UPDATE RECORD SET name=?, stok=?, jual=?, image=? WHERE id=?";

        SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
        statement.bindString(1, name);
        statement.bindString(2, stok);
        statement.bindString(3, jual);
        statement.bindBlob(4, image);
        statement.bindDouble(5, (double)id);
        statement.execute();
        database.close();
    }

    //deleteData
    public void deleteData(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        //query to delete record using id
        String sql = "DELETE FROM RECORD WHERE id=?";
        SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
        statement.clearBindings();
        statement.bindDouble(1, (double)id);
        statement.execute();
        database.close();
    }

    public Cursor getData(String sql){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
        return database.rawQuery(sql, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBLNAME_RECORD +
                "(" +
                RECORD_COl_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                RECORD_COL_NAME + " TEXT," +
                RECORD_COL_STOK + " TEXT," +
                RECORD_COL_JUAL + " TEXT," +
                RECORD_COL_IMAGE + " BLOB," +
                RECORD_COL_IMAGEPATH + " TEXT" +
                ")"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

## Additional re storing images in DB

The 256k limitation has been chosen as being perhaps a reasonable size to not store images in the DB. I guess when you say the *2MB download limit*, you mean that you've encountered a CursorWindow having a 2MB limit and hence the need to store image paths.

Even 256k might be too large as that could result in a 7 rows per CursorWindow. As such there could be issues. However, considering the findings of [SQlite - 35% Faster Than The Filesystem](https://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html) then at 100k you are potentially better off storing the images in the database. *As such experimentation may determine a better limitation.*

Comment: error: constructor SQLiteHelper in class SQLiteHelper cannot be applied to given types;
        mDBHlpr = new SQLiteHelper(this);
                  ^
  required: Context,String,CursorFactory,int
  found: MainActivity
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: @Kira this is a demo only based upon yours. As I had to create a database (your onCreate was empty) I used a shorter constructor. If you bear with me I'll drop in the complete DatabaseHelper class so you can compare the changes.

Comment: @Kira should also add that MainActivity is really just a demo of how the StoreImage class can be used, you'd be expected to integrate the usage into your code.

Comment: Thanks, can you drop the complete database helper class?

Comment: @Kira, that's what I did. See the bottom of the answer i.e. the section entitle **Additional SQliteHelper.java**.